# Converting JPG file to PDF file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have tried the following code for appending date with the file and copy to another folder location. It is working properly with the same file extension. I want to change files that have .jpg extension to .pdf extension.

```
$action = { 
$SourceDir= 'E:\start'
$targetDir = 'E:\end\'

set-location -path $sourceDir

$files = get-childitem -recurse 
foreach ($file in $files)
{
 $strippedFileName = $file.BaseName;
  $extension = $file.Extension;
  $crtime=$file.CreationTime.toString('_dd_MM_yyyy');
  $sourceFilePath = $file.DirectoryName;
  $DestinationFile = $targetDir + $sourcefilepath.TrimStart($sourceDir) + "\" + $strippedFileName +$crtime + $extension;
  Copy-Item $file.FullName  -Destination $DestinationFile -Recurse -Force
}
              }    

### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

I want to do some changes so that if an image is placed in the source directory, it should change into PDF in the destination directory.

Comment: Have you tried anything to convert the files?

Comment: Just changing the extension of the .jpg file won't convert it into a .pdf file. Therefore, you won't be able to open the renamed file.

Comment: I answered a similar problem a while a go: [Using Powershell to Print a Folder of Text files to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826100/using-powershell-to-print-a-folder-of-text-files-to-pdf-retaining-the-oiringal/49826836#49826836).  Clearly, it is talking about text files and not images, but you might be able to modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: @Paxz: yes. but its not working

Comment: @TobyU: yes. it's not opening. Are there any other solutions to this?

Comment: @boxdog: I didn't get what you are saying

Comment: @IvanRajadurai, I was saying that my previous answer demonstrates how to convert text files to PDF files using the 'Print to PDF' functionality.  You can (probably) use it as a starting point to creating a script that does the same for JPG files.

Comment: @boxdog: could you please edit that code and place it here? so that it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no way to convert an image into an PDF by only using PowerShell and changing the file extension won't help either.

You could install a PDF printer and build a PowerShell script to print your image into a PDF file using the PDF printer. Just google for "PDF printer" to find a lot of useful freeware tools to do so.