# How to save output of any powershell script in pdf format using powershell?

Tags: powershell

Instead of:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Force | ConvertTo-Html -Body "<H2>C Drive Details</H2>" >> $OutFile
```

I want the output in pdf format not html

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/e4bf56b2-b5d2-4bc0-8d43-cc43ceeebf30/printing-pdfs-to-a-specific-printer?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: As far as I know there's no native PDF handling in Powershell. I've used a third-party library like [PdfSharp](http://pdfsharp.net/) before ([Hello World example](http://merill.net/2013/06/creating-pdf-files-dynamically-with-powershell/)) It's not as simple as just sending output to a 'PDF Printer' though.

Comment: You might be able to adapt my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826100/using-powershell-to-print-a-folder-of-text-files-to-pdf-retaining-the-oiringal/49826836#49826836

Answer (score 1):

If you go to this website http://www.powertheshell.com/modules/

You can download the PDFTools module and extract the contents to your modules path and then `Import-Module PDFTools`, this will give you a new command `Out-PTSPDF` which you can pass your results to.

@JamesC is right there is no "native" way to complete this.